# Adding securesocial module to a play 2.2.1 project

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, dependencies

I want to add [securesocial](http://securesocial.ws/guide/installation.html) to my play project to easily integrate the signing up/login taks for users. However, when adding the dependecy in my `build.sbt` file I get:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: securesocial#securesocial;2.1.2: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: securesocial#securesocial;2.1.2: no
t found
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:213)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:104)
        at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:51)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:60)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRet
ries$1(Locks.scala:81)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:
102)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:60)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:101)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:97)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:116)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:121)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala
:1144)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala
:1142)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1
165)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1
163)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1167)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1162)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
        at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1170)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1135)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1113)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:23
7)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:23
7)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestric
tions.scala:160)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: securesocial#sec
uresocial;2.1.2: not found
[error] Total time: 6 s, completed 22.11.2013 10:15:38
```

I added the dependency like that:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "securesocial" % "securesocial" % "2.1.2"
)
```

Whats wrong?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe try (in build.sbt)...

```
resolvers += "sbtplugins" at "http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases"
```

Answer (score 1):

My build.sbt resolvers looks like this for Securesocial:

resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-releases", url("http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample build.sbt file that works well

```
name := "name"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "master-SNAPSHOT"
)

resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-snapshots", new URL("http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
)

play.Project.playScalaSettings
```

Comment: He probably doesn't adding the resolver path for dependency.You need to add aditional resolver path to get related files to your depency needs.In this case it's securesocial and its reolver url http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-snapshots/"